# Missing Windows functions

Tags: windows-7

I encountered a computer at the job today, which has the following problem:

- Windows shortcuts do not work, at all (Win+L to lock, Ctrl+Shift+Esc for processes, etc)
- Can't reboot, shutdown nor lock by their buttons on the start menu
- Network features are missing too, the biggest offender of them all is RPC, for remote printing.

Have any of you encountered such a problem before?

I tried doing system repair, it didn't work, and the machine has system restore off.

Comment: Is there any reason to not just fresh reinstall the system? Finding the cause might be interesting, but trying to repair such a system would just waste time.

Comment: It has a lot of important data and propietary programs we don't have at our disposal right now. We'll do that as a last resort, though.

Comment: Is this PC on a work Domain?

Comment: Work domain.
Are you implying it's a policy problem?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Start menu - -> Run - -> Type command - -> gpedit.msc - -> Local Group Policy editor will open. - -> Left Side - User Configuration - -> Administrative Template --- > Window Component - -> Window/file Explorer.

Right panel - -> Find - -> Turn off Windows+X hotkey  - -> Disabled.

Restart your PC. Might it resolve your problem.

Source taken from : [You have to disable it, Dont enable it. ]

http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/

Comment: This solves the first problem, we still have number 2 and 3.